# How to combine the results using SPARQL (dbpedia.org with linkedmdb.org or freebase.com)

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, freebase, dbpedia

I need to get all awarded movies on 80th Award Ceremony
I tried to write SPARQL query:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix movie: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>
prefix award: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film_awards_ceremony/180/>

select distinct ?film ?award where  {
  { ?film a movie:film.
    ?award a movie:film_awards_ceremony.
  } union 

  { ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film }
  ?film rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

But the [result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20movie%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.linkedmdb.org%2Fresource%2Fmovie%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20award%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.linkedmdb.org%2Fpage%2Ffilm_awards_ceremony%2F180%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Ffilm%20%3Faward%20where%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Ffilm%20a%20movie%3Afilm.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Faward%20a%20movie%3Afilm_awards_ceremony.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20union%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Ffilm%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFilm%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffilm%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on) is full movies list.

I found the data I need also here: https://www.freebase.com/m/02pgky2

How to combine (union) these entities in a right way ?
If is not possible - How to get the result from freebase using SPARQL and dbpedia.org?

Comment: What you mean by "the result is full movies list"?  What is it that you're *trying* to retrieve?